# No solution on the internet worked for Module 'google_maps_flutter' not found

Tags: xcode, flutter, dart, app-store-connect

I am trying to archive my flutter app to publish it to App Store Connect. Then I got this problem and I tried every single solution on the internet but nothing seem to work so I need help.

Here is the problem:

[image: This is the problem]

Answer (score 3):

This will install all dependencies for iOS.

```
cd ios
pod install
```

You must see an output similar to this:

```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing FMDB (2.7.5)
Installing Flutter (1.0.0)
Installing GoogleMaps (4.2.0)
```

If Xcode is opened when running `pod install`, you'll be prompted to either `Keep Xcode Version` or to `Read From Disk`.

Choose: **`Read From Disk`**.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by double clicking and running `Runner.xcworkspace` instead of `Runner.xcodeproj`

Answer (score 0):

Have you fulfilled all the requirements related with the app-delegate.. in the IOS section?

Because the problem seems to be connecting google maps flutter package with the IOS.